# Using reserved words in column names

Tags: mysql, sql, database

this is some simple code but I just don't know why I can't use this word as the entity of the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
key INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);
```

I realized I can't use "key" if I use key the mysql will ask me to check the syntax but if I use "id" or any others the table will be created.

Anyone know how I can create the entity name into key?  Not something important since I can just use id instead of key but since I found this error I wonna see if there's a way to get it work.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to find more meaningful names than SQL reserved words.  Perhaps `UserId` would be a good name -- and to the casual observer, it is much more informative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I use certain words as table/column names in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/why-cant-i-use-certain-words-as-table-column-names-in-mysql)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your Comment is naïve. There are over a thousand words reserved by various database systems when I last did a tally. It is not at all obvious when devising a name whether it might collide with a reserved word.

Comment: @BasilBourque . . . `KEY` is part of the SQL Syntax -- think `PRIMARY KEY`.  There is nothing naive about thinking that people creating tables in SQL should know the basic syntactic elements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can still use `key` if you want to. Just wrap it with backtick,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
(
    `key` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);
```

but as an advise, refrain from using any reserved keyword to avoid future problems. `:)`

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: ah alright that worked...I tried \ thought that might be how to do it since in php \ escapes the character hahah....thanks a lot ^_^ do learn something new everyday

Answer (score 4):

## Trailing Underscore

Simple solution: **Add a trailing underscore** to every name.

The SQL spec [SQL:2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) explicitly promises to never use a trailing underscore on any keyword, neither now nor in the future.

Example: `key_`

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758863/642706) to a similar question, *h2 database column name is reserved word*.