# Oops! used a reserved word to name a column

Tags: google-bigquery

I made a bigquery table with one column named "row" (no quotes)... doh! Now my sql won't compile if I reference that column:

```
SELECT row, etext FROM [hcd.hdctext] LIMIT 1; =ERROR"
```

I did not see "ROW" as a reserved word in GQL...

I saw that in some systems you can get around that problem with backticks :

```
SELECT `row`, etext FROM [hcd.hdctext] LIMIT 1;
```

([Using reserved words in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725233/using-reserved-words-in-column-names))

Any way to do the same in bigquery? Otherwise I will have to reupload my 200M of data and start again. Seems like changing a field name would not be a big feature.. but I am naive about how the data is stored.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

BigQuery Legacy SQL uses `[]` as quote chars. BigQuery Standard SQL uses backticks.

So, for Legacy SQL, just use

```
SELECT [row], etext from [hcd.hdctext]
```

If you want to rename it permanently, there isn't a way to do that currently, but you can rename it in a query and save the results... just use

```
SELECT [row] as newname, .... FROM [hcd.hdctext]
```

and specify 'allow large results' and a destination table name.

Comment: Done! I would have never have found that... Thanks!

Comment: For the record - in the StandardSQL syntax you would use backticks ` instead of square brackets.

Comment: If that column is a repeated field, then the backticks don't help. Did anyone solve this issue?

Comment: Another "niche" cache: if the column is part of a STRUCT, then the backticks do help.

Answer (score 1):

[DOCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql) - CTRL-F "bracket" and it'll take you right to the paragraph in the docs.

This is multiple years late, but here is a link to the documentation for future reference, as per suggestion of [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385132/chris).  I could not post it as a direct reply, but the question was marked answered long ago.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions work.

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE a WHERE DATE(time) = "2022-07-07" and a.[RESERVED KEYWORD] = 'X'
```