# Is there any specific symbol for dedicating column name for BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have BigQuery with column name `order`.
In this case when I try to select this column I have the error: `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword ORDER`.
If it some way around this error, the way where BigQuery takes it as the name of the column and not a function.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905842/oops-used-a-reserved-word-to-name-a-column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oops! used a reserved word to name a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905842/oops-used-a-reserved-word-to-name-a-column)

Comment: the solution was used `` for orders, there is from questions, but not from answers. Thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ([Oops! used a reserved word to name a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905842/oops-used-a-reserved-word-to-name-a-column)) use either backticks (``) for standard sql or square brackets ([]) for legacy sql to escape the name.