# SQL syntax error when I use column name "from"

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have problem with query, anybody see something bad?

```
INSERT INTO messages (subject, from, recipient, text, time)
VALUES
('Welcome in King of the States!','The Game','$username','Hello $username, THIS MESSAGE IS DISPLAYED IN ENGLISH AUTOMATICLY SORRY FOR THAT! this game is in baby stadium so if you will see any bugs, please report them to our help desc system','$time')
```

Error from sql:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, recipient, text, time) VALUES ('Welcome in King of the States!','The Gam' at line 1
```

Comment: `FROM` is a reserved word in SQL. You can either escape it with backticks, or change the column name.

Comment: Ok -..- That will be really much of editing :DD I going to try that

Comment: Ok it work.. I changed "from" to "sender" and "for" to "recipient" Thanks you ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using reserved words in column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725233/using-reserved-words-in-column-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from` is a mysql reserved word. try placing `from` in backtick

Like below:

```
`from`
```

Comment: You need to accept answers, instead of changing the title :)

Comment: I know, but I cant do that in the first 10 minutes - just 3 minutes now

Comment: You should be able to accept AN answer now.

Comment: @TomášAresakMalčánek You are able to accept other answer :) Not only this ;)

Answer (score 1):

try to do:

```
INSERT INTO messages (`subject`, `from`, `recipient`, `text`, `time`)
VALUES
('Welcome in King of the States!','The Game','$username','Hello $username, THIS MESSAGE IS DISPLAYED IN ENGLISH AUTOMATICLY SORRY FOR THAT! this game is in baby stadium so if you will see any bugs, please report them to our help desc system','$time')
```

Answer (score 1):

From is the reserve keyword in the mysql so use the below query:

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`subject`, `from`, `recipient`, `text`, `time`)
VALUES
('Welcome in King of the States!',
 'The Game','$username',
'Hello $username, 
THIS MESSAGE IS DISPLAYED IN ENGLISH AUTOMATICLY SORRY FOR THAT! this game is in baby stadium so if you will see any bugs, please report them to our help desc system','$time')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"INSERT INTO messages SET subject='Welcome in King of the States!',from='The Game',recipient='".$username."',text='Hello.$username', time=''";
```

Comment: That won't work - you still need to escape the FROM.

Comment: remove from field add change field name

Answer (score 0):

Instruction:

from is a keyword in mysql. So you can not use directly in query like this.
You need to parse it every time and for that use backtick

use it like  `from`