# how to make 'from' as column name in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Since from is a keyword in MySql ,I'm facing trouble in creating a table having from as one of the column name.I saw one related ques asked ,but it tells how to apply queries on a table that already contains from as one of the attribute .Can anyone help me out.!

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain: Don't use a reserved word as table/colum idenitifier

Comment: Actually its my assignment of sql in which we are already given table name and its attributes..So,no other option left,but to use it.!

Comment: This question has been asked/answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725233/using-reserved-words-in-column-names)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your column name doesn't match the pattern `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` or it conflicts with any [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) then you'll need to escape it using backticks:

```
SELECT `from` FROM `table`
```

Note that having conflicting names tends to be really annoying because of the special treatment they need, so please, for the sake of anyone that ever has to work with this database, **don't do it**.

Answer (score 0):

`from` is a reserved word in SQL, and I'd strongly advice against using it as a name. If you absolutely have to, you can escape it by using backtiks (`):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN `from` VARCHAR(10)
```

Comment: those are backticks

Comment: D'oh. Dunno what came over me there